# How to catch ' Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded' when shell_exec("ping $ip")

Tags: php, html, error-handling, fatal-error

Im doing a page that ping a range of IPs, when it ping an ip sometimes it got an error "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded" and stops.

i tried to catch the error with:

```
function catch_fatal_error(){
  GLOBAL $tmp_ip;
  GLOBAL $IP5;
  $iparray = explode(".", $tmp_ip);
  $IP1 = $iparray[0];
  $IP2 = $iparray[1];
  $IP3 = $iparray[2];
  $IP4 = $iparray[3];

  $last_error =  error_get_last();
 
  if(isset($last_error['type']) && $last_error['type']==E_ERROR)
  {
    ping($IP1,$IP2,$IP3,$IP4,$IP5);
  }
}

register_shutdown_function('catch_fatal_error');
```

but it just works once.

The line that makes the error:

```
$comando = shell_exec("ping -a -l 8 -n 5 $tmp_ip");
```

Comment: You don't show the `ping()` function.

Comment: As @AbraCadaver already mentioned - you have to provide `ping()` function for us and/or place that calls `$comando`.